# Overwrite each HTML tag with spaces so the position of each text character doesn’t shift

Tags: python, html, spacy

In python, I'd like to overwrite each HTML tag with spaces so the position of each text character in the string doesn’t shift.

For example `<p>` would be replaced with three spaces    .

Below my best attempt to write code that achieves my goal, but it feels too brittle and complicated for such a simple task:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.html_redacted_with_whitespaces = ""
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.html_redacted_with_whitespaces +=  " " * (len(tag) + 2)
        
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.html_redacted_with_whitespaces +=  " " * (len(tag) + 3)
        
    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.html_redacted_with_whitespaces +=  data
        
parser = MyHTMLParser()
test_html = """<html><head><title>Test</title></head>
<body><h1>Replace my tags with spaces!</h1></body></html>"""
parser.feed(test_html)

len(test_html), len(parser.html_redacted_with_whitespaces)
print(test_html)
print(parser.html_redacted_with_whitespaces)
```

Output:

```
<html><head><title>Test</title></head>
<body><h1>Replace my tags with spaces!</h1></body></html>
                   Test               
          Replace my tags with spaces!
```

My goal is to redact html with white-spaces before feeding it into spacy.
It's necessary to redact html before feeding it into spacy so the html tags do "confuse" the nlp model.
This issue is partially discussed in : https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4177

The reason I would like to keep the spacing intact is to be able to use spacy's NER `doc.ents` for highlighting. Later in post-processing I inject my own tags own tags in the original html.

I googled around but could not find a turn key solution.

Comment: keeping the exact same size of the suppressed tag for hidding it may not be the best way of an effective redacting. If security is really needed most of the tags might be guessed back (three spaces before a capital letter = `<p>`) and so on. But them, I don't see as the html tags themselves could be any threat.

Comment: That said, this approach is ingenious. but it might work with a call to `re.sub` providing an appropriate callback

Comment: Note that extra whitespace in spaCy may also cause strange results. I would suggest that you remove the whitespace but save the character offsets instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression based substitutions, which allows a callback to know which will be the replacement text:

```
import re

test_html = """<html><head><title>Test</title></head>
<body><h1>Replace my tags with spaces!</h1></body></html>"""


filtered_text = re.sub("<.*?>",lambda m: " " * len(m.group(0))   , test_html)
```

The callback is passed a regexp "match" object for each match, it does have a "group" method which returns the string for each matched group in the regexp, and then we use its `len`.

The regexp itself is trivial, and a bit naive: it just looks for any oppening `<` and the next. `>` - if any escaping is used for those (as inside a `<script>`, `<cdata>` or comment tag), it simply won't work.